# anexar nueva app

Tags: django

Quiero agregarle una nueva app a mi proyecto pero no se cómo hacerlo. Ya cree los templates, mis views, y urls, pero no sé cómo hacer para que se anexe.

**models.py** (datos)

```
from django.db import models

class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (

        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)

class ActualizacionEmpleado(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey('Empleados', null = False, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.empleado)

class DatosPersonales(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES = (

        ('C', 'Casado'),
        ('S', 'Soltero'),
        ('V', 'Viudo')
    )

    OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES = (

        ('B', 'Bachiller'),
        ('U', 'Universitaria'),
        ('T', 'Tecnico superior')
    )

    empleado = models.ForeignKey('Empleados', null = False, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    grado_instruccion = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_de_hijos = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.empleado)
```

La ultima clase, es la agregada.

**forms.py** (datospersonales)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from datos.models import Empleados
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Select

class DatospersonalesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Empleados

        fields = [
            'direccion',
            'estado_civil',
            'grado_instruccion',
            'numero_de_hijos',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'direccion': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca su direccion'}),
            'estado_civil': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Estado civil'}),
            'grado_instruccion': Select(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Grado de instruccion'}),
            'numero_de_hijos': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'number','placeholder':'Numero de hijos'}),            
        }
```

**views.py** (datospersonales)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, DetailView
from datos.models import Empleados
from datos.forms import EmpleadoForm

class DatospersonalesView(CreateView):
    model = Empleados
    form_class = EmpleadoForm
    template_name = 'datospersonales/formulario.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('datospersonales:index')

class DatospersonalesUpdate(UpdateView): # actualizar mi registro
    model = Empleados
    form_class = EmpleadoForm
    template_name = 'datospersonales/formulario.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('datospersonales:index')

class DatospersonalesDelete(DeleteView): # borrar un registro
    model = Empleados
    template_name = 'datospersonales/eliminar.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('datospersonales:index')

class DetalleFormulario(DetailView): # ver detalles de un registro
    model = Empleados
    template_name = 'datospersonales/detalles.html'
```

**urls.py** (datospersonales)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import ListView
from datos.views import DatospersonalesView, DatospersonalesUpdate, DatospersonalesDelete, DetalleFormulario
from .models import Empleados, ActualizacionEmpleado

app_name = 'datosempleados'

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'listado', 
        ListView.as_view(
        model = Empleados,
        template_name = 'datospersonales/index.html'
        ), 
        name='listado-index'),

    path('listado/formulario', 
        DatospersonalesView.as_view(), 
        name='agregar-formulario'),

    path('listado/actualizar/<int:pk>/',
        DatospersonalesUpdate.as_view(), 
        name='actualizar-formulario'),

    path('listado/eliminar/<int:pk>/', 
        DatospersonalesDelete.as_view(), 
        name='eliminar-formulario'),

    path('listado/detalle/<int:pk>/', 
        DetalleFormulario.as_view(), 
        name='detalle-formulario'),
]
```

Los templates también están creados.

Pero no sé como hacer para que mi app *datospersonales* se cargue, de ser posible desde mi formulario en la app datos.

Sé que estoy pidiendo demasiado pero es que soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres que se anexe, a qué haces referencia? Hay algo que no funcione, no especificas bien qué necesitas exactamente. De todas formas si de algo te sirve, no olvides agregar tu app dentro de la configuración de Django en el archivo `settings.py`, en `INSTALLED_APPS` debe estar la nueva aplicación que creaste, para así poder identificar los modelos y todo lo que Django necesita para integrar tu app con todo el proyecto

Comment: cree otra app pero que tiene que ver con la anterior por lo que quiero es que cuando se introduzcan datos dentro del primer formulario una vez se le de a sumit este me direccione al nuevo formulario y me permita realizar el sumit tambien enviandome al inicio